# zsh prompt losing customization when using `sudo su`

Tags: shell, zsh, sudo, prompt, su

My current zsh prompt is:

```
prompt='%F{013}%2~%f$(git_super_status)%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)$ %f'
```

It looks something like:

```
Documents/multi-git-status:master↑5●2✚1…$
```

However, when I use `sudo su` it becomes `blueray-PC#`

```
Documents/multi-git-status:master↑5●2✚1…$ sudo su
[sudo] password for blueray:   
blueray-PC#
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Although not the answer to your question, it seems that the real thing you want to do is have a nice prompt as every user. I highly recommend taking a look at https://ohmyz.sh/ . It has a gigantic amount of themes and plugins for nice extra zsh features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo su` is deprecated and will indeed mess up your environment.
Use `sudo -i` instead.

(This also has the advantage that it works on systems without `su`)

**Edit:** I forgot something:
Add `export PS1="%F{013}%2~%f$(git_super_status)%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)$ %f"`
at the end of `/root/.zshrc`

Comment: `sudo -i` is also showing the same behavior. Changed my prompt to `blueray-PC# `

Comment: Sorry, my edit should work

Comment: Works for me on my Mac. 

Tried this running zsh on macOS Big Sur (11.6) using iTerm2 shell with Oh My Zsh.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this with `sudo -s` in macOS Catalina, until I realized that:

- `sudo -s` starts an Interactive shell, so it uses the zshenv & zshrc profiles, not zprofile & zlogin
- In macOS, /etc/zschrc will set the prompt, so your only opportunity to override is with .zshrc.
- Even though you're getting a root shell, with sudo -s it is reading the user profiles from your own home directory, not /var/root.